# SQL - UPDATE / SET statement query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I wanted to update 1 column from a table present in a database maintained in SQL 2008 R2.

The entire column contains same value of data type int and I want to change to different value of same int data type.

When do we use single apostrophe in SET statement & when to avoid or not use it?

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET COLUMNNAME = X
```

OR

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET COLUMNNAME = 'X'
```

Appreciate any suggestions/advise. Thanks.

Comment: I am guessing from trial and error, if it is varchar/nvarchar it needs to be enclosed in apostrophe. Does not matter if the value is of is int data type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL, single quotes are used around string values. Other "values", like integers, references to other columns etc, should never be single quoted.